# How to add dynamically changing parameters to a breadcrumb in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, php

I am using breadcrumbs in my zend application, the question is I have to use dynamicallly changing parameters.

In my breadcrumb it should be:

> Manage hotels -> hotel1 -> rates -> add rate

the  hotel is changing, but I can only do

> Manage hotels-> rates -> add rate

I can't add the dynamically changing hotel name to my breadcrumb, 
how can I do this, is there any way to do this?

Comment: `Zend_Navigation` works best with a static structure. Perhaps it isn't the best solution for your application

Comment: oh really ............. then i have to look for another option , thanks lkke .....................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change the breadcrumbs dynamically. You can generate a navigation object from the database, You can find out how to create a navigation object in the following link..

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.pages.html

You can keep the Hotel Name as a hidden due (0), but to enable them for the breadcrumbs use the following: 
$this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setRenderInvisible(TRUE);